# undefined is not an object evaluating (_reactnative.Modal.propTypes.animationType) after updating react native version to 0.59.4

Tags: android, react-native

i have updated react native version from 0.55 to 0.59 and facing an serious issue and tried everything but nothing works.It is giving me error that

```
undefined is not an object evaluating (_reactnative.Modal.propTypes.animationType)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Fuelex",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fabric": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-imagepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-linkedin": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-linkedin-login": "^1.44.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.3.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-paypal-wrapper": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-simple-time-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-timeline-listview": "^0.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.15",
    "rn-viewpager": "^1.2.9",
    "tipsi-twitter": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have tried updating packages but nothing solves this error.I have also installed props-types package from using npm but it does not works ? Help me in solving this issue .Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of the section it's complaining about? It seems your implementation might be wrong after the update (native propTypes was deprecated a few versions back). Implementation should be like this - https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: there is no error in code...after updating react native version its giving error like this...Its given error in GestureButton.js file in the console....and this file is in node module package

Comment: i thought this would be in react navigation or react native gesture handler so i updated both

Comment: Can you post your code snippet where you are using Modal?

Comment: actually....i dont know why this problem occurs ? i had upadated react native version and this gives me error after update .

Comment: @VipinDubey this probably means that one of your libraries is out of date or not compatible with new react native version. Delete your node modules, clear your npm/yarn cache, re install modes and try again. Otherwise try and pinpoint which library it is and open an issue on their git repo if you're sure you're on the latest version.

Comment: Yeah i have updated and it works fine but during hot reloading feature it gives me error that undefined is not an object evaluating 'update.modules.forEah'.How can i solve this?

Comment: That's a different issue it seems. I would open a separate ticket for that one. Is your original issue fixed then?

Comment: Yes it has been fixed !

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it by these steps..

1. Remove installed package `react-native-material-dropdown`

   `yarn remove react-native-material-dropdown`
2. Install new packages `react-native-material-dropdown-v2` and `react-native-paper`

   `yarn add react-native-material-dropdown-v2 react-native-paper`
3. Swap `react-native-material-dropdown` to `react-native-material-dropdown-v2` in your code

   e.g.
   `import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown'` to `import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown-v2'`